# AngularJS: How do I hide clicked element in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-hide

I'm totally new to angular and I'm finding that doing simple things aren't as obvious to me? I have a list of items that I display using ng-repeat. I simply want to hide the element once I click on an element within that scope. I'd like to do it the "angular" way with good practices.. just not sure what that is.

This is html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FruitsCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
                <p>{{fruit.name}}</p>
                <button ng-click="hideMe()">hide li</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Fruits', function () {
    var Fruits = [{
        name: "banana"
    }, {
        name: "watermelon"
    }, {
        name: "strawberry"
    }];

    return Fruits;
});


function FruitsCtrl($scope, Fruits) {
    $scope.fruits = Fruits;

    $scope.hideMe = function () {
        alert('hide this li');
    };
}
```

I have this on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hS5q8/2/

Help or direction would be great! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**ngHide**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide) directive. In Example added a property *hide*, *ngHide* will hide *li* if this property is **true**.

*HTML*

```
<li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-hide="fruit.hide">
    <p>{{fruit.name}}</p>
    <button ng-click="hideMe(fruit)">hide li</button>
</li>
```

*Angularjs Method*

```
$scope.hideMe = function (fruit) {
    fruit.hide=true;
    alert('hide this li');
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/hS5q8/3/)

Comment: I was wondering how that worked with ng-hide. Thank you!! Works great!

Comment: I think you can also skip the function: `ng-click="fruit.hide=true"`

Comment: @FooL, But OP might need to do some operations in that method

Comment: @Satpal, true, this is a good gold plated answer. i'm trying to provide the simplest answer to the original question "how do I hide the element when clicked?" :) both works

Comment: @FooL, I totally agree with your solution and that will work. No doubt in that